# Qt: Make transparent QGraphicsItem objects obscure each other

Tags: qt, qt5

I would like to add several QGraphicsItem objects to a scene and have them all be transparent (i.e. visible but not completely opaque) with respect to another QPixmapItem background image which is also part of the scene yet obscure each other.

At the moment I am not sure whether this is possible it all. Making all objects in question children of some other QGraphicsItem and then making the parent transparent does not have the desired effect so I guess I'm looking for some completely different approach but I have no idea where to start on this.

EDIT: It seems my explanation was not quite clear enough, I will try to add an example in a few hours time.

Comment: I would like to help you, however it is not very clear to me how, since _does not have the desired effect_ does not explain much about your problem. Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what causes you trouble and I would be very glad to take a look and try to help you.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, you wish to have QGraphicItems which have an opacity less than 100% so that the background image is visible. 
To achieve the same, you can use the [set opacity function](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#setOpacity).